# How to do table of simple data in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a collection of double. (For example: 5.48, 6.78, 3.00 ....) I want to put all data in scrollable table like:

5.48 6.78 3.00 4.39 ...
   ...................................
   ...................................
   6.98 1.48 ...................

I do not know how to realize it with DataGridView, because this component must have fixed count of columns with specific name (may be I make mistake, I am newbie in Windows Forms).
I'll be happy if you say me how do it or give links with description.

Comment: Does it need to interact with the user other than scrolling or is it acceptable to just display the data as read-only?

Comment: You can add more columns to the DataGridView at runtime.  But if this is just a stream of numbers, maybe a ListView is what you want instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y62k236c.aspx) control.

This is not a databound control — you'll have to create new label controls from your data and add them to the panel by hand — but it can help automatically layout your records and have them wrap across and then downward.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TableLayoutPanel you can set the number of rows and columns

```
TableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 5;
TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 10;
```

...